# How should I handle a user logging out of Facebook but remaining logged in on my website?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

The way I have set it up is that when the user first visits the site, it will ask them to login with Facebook. It gets an access token and creates a session on my site.

If at any point the user logs out of facebook, say in another tab, the session will still exists within in my application.

The only way I can see to detect if the user is still logged into Facebook is re-requesting an access token as there doesnt seem to be a way to check if an existing access token is still valid.

I did try simply doing:

```
file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=xxx')
```

but, since the token is no longer valid (as the user has logged out), file_get_contents returns an error, although, viewing this in the browser shows the oauth exception but im assuming file_get_contents is erroring because of the HTTP response code

Comment: Also, I'd prefer to not have to go through the whole 2 step process of getting a code from the query string then sending that off. I'd like for my site to be able to detect that the current access token is no longer valid and notify the user they must login back into Facebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this I think:

```
@$data=file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=xxx');
foreach ($http_response_header as $rh) if (substr($rh, 0, 4)=='HTTP') list(,$status,)=explode(' ', $rh, 3);
if ($status==200 && $data)
    //Token is good, parse data
else
    //Token is no good
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of questions in here .. i would just share some insight:

1. If a user logs out FB in 1 tab of a browser he will be logged out of all tabs
2. If an FB application has asked for a user's permissions like offline_acess they can show   them any relevant content they want to if they have maintained some sore of fb id and their own id mapping .. the access_token shall be needed for fetching any information ofcourse
3. access_token remains valid if you have not explicitly asked for an access_token with expiry date ..
4. access_token changes if the user changes any FB credentials. which a FB app cannot detect

Comment: 1. Yes, I know, when I say session, I mean my own applications session

Comment: 2. But if a user hits my page, then for example go into another tab and happens to log out of Facebook, comes back to my site, and attempt to perform an action that requires the application to say write a status for that user, the application needs to know that the user has logged out of facebook so that it can request a new access token